# Plot lists in different subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have data in lists that I want to plot, which looks like this:

```
time = [1633093403.754783918, 1633093403.755350983, 1633093403.760918965, 1633093403.761298577, 1633093403.761340378, 1633093403.761907443]
data = [[0,1], [1,1], [0,0], [1,0], [0,1], [1,1]]
```

Now I want to plot the first element of each list in `data` in a subplot and the second one in another one. So, all elements in `data[n][0]` in one plot and `data[n][1]` in another one.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
time = [1633093403.754783918, 1633093403.755350983, 1633093403.760918965, 1633093403.761298577, 1633093403.761340378, 1633093403.761907443]
data = [[0,1], [1,1], [0,0], [1,0], [0,1], [1,1]]


data_0 = [i[0] for i in data]
data_1 = [i[1] for i in data]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot(time, data_0)
ax2.plot(time, data_1)
plt.show()
```